# Should the color of a texture be adjusted for display on a television?

Tags: textures, c, console, image

If a 24bit RGB image with a range of 0-255 per channel is displayed on a television that displays a range of approx. 16-235 per channel, color detail will be lost, correct?

If so, should images be pre-processed to only store a valid range? I would like to do this with code, not in a picture editing application. I vaguely recall reading that a linear mapping is not the best way to do this, but unfortunately I can't locate the article I was reading! What is this process called? What other details do I need to know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some color data will be lost or changed regardless of your texture format. However, a bigger problem will be gamma correction. Gamma correction can be a tricky subject since your game will not appear visually the same across all display technologies and finding a single solution is not going to be easy.

These might help you out:

- https://maddieman.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/gamma-correction-and-linear-colour-space-simplified/
- https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch24.html
- http://blog.wolfire.com/2010/02/Gamma-correct-lighting
- https://renderwonk.com/blog/index.php/archive/adventures-with-gamma-correct-rendering/
- https://poynton.ca/notes/colour_and_gamma/GammaFAQ.html

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am already doing gamma correction at load time with libpng, which helps, but I might have to look again at the code after reading the above information as the images are still 'washed out' on a television.

Answer (score 5):

Linear mapping is probably not the *best* solution (which I believe involves converting your RGB to a [CIE colorspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space), scaling there, and converting back), but it is very easy to implement, and the range difference is small enough it probably won't matter.

If you use [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html), it can automatically do this when loading the image, by passing SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB to the load functions.

[Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee418274.aspx) says to clamp, and recommends doing it in a pixel shader. (Linear scaling should also be easy in one.) It also mentions chroma crawl, which in my experience is a much more annoying phenomenon when working on TV displays.

Comment: SOIL! I forgot about that library. It has helped me in the past with some ideas. Thanks for the links.